# Variable is being truncated and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I have a bit of code that goes something like this:

```
function getTotal() {
    let total = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let N = couldReturnANumberOrUndefined() | 0.00;
        total += N;
    }

    return total;
}

function couldReturnANumberOrUndefined() {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (r === 0) {
        return undefined;
    } else {
        return 1.5;
    }
}
```

The idea is that if the function returns undefined, we just say it was 0.00, hence the pipe.

The issue is that when it should return 1.5 - and I can *see* in the debugger that the return value is in fact 1.5, by the time it gets to be put into price it is always truncated down to the lowest integer value, and I have no idea why.

I've tried putting `.toFixed(2)` at the end of the price variable in various configurations but that hasn't worked.

Anyone know why this is and how to stop it?

Many thanks!

Comment: `couldReturnANumberOrUndefined() | 0.00` -> `couldReturnANumberOrUndefined() || 0.00`

Comment: Number does NOT have significant digits. You are using bitwise or not an or

Comment: `|` is a bitwise operation, it converts its arguments to integers.